# PHP-jQuery: time difference between two dates returns NaN

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to setup a counter that shows time elapsed from the moment a user logs in but it keeps returning NaN when I get the datetime from the database.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
{
var sess_rec_id = /*record id value*/
    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {last_rec_id: sess_rec_id},
    cache: false,
    success :  function(r)
        {
            var startDateTime = new Date(r.start_time);
            var startStamp = startDateTime.getTime();

            var newDate = new Date();
            var newStamp = newDate.getTime();

            var timer;

            function updateClock() {
                newDate = new Date();
                newStamp = newDate.getTime();
                var diff = Math.round((newStamp-startStamp)/1000);

                var d = Math.floor(diff/(24*60*60));
                diff = diff-(d*24*60*60);
                var h = Math.floor(diff/(60*60));
                diff = diff-(h*60*60);
                var m = Math.floor(diff/(60));
                diff = diff-(m*60);
                var s = diff;

                $("#countup").html(d+" day(s), "+h+" hour(s), "+m+" minute(s), "+s+" second(s)");
            }
            setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

console.log(r.start_time) shows me the date as '2016-10-24 13:57:30'

However, the ouput I'm getting on the browser is NaN day(s), NaN hour(s), NaN minute(s), NaN second(s).

Any ideas how to parse this properly?

Comment: What does `console.log(startStamp)` show?

Comment: the console.log shows NaN for startStamp

Comment: Are you sure that this is the r.start_time? Because I've tested it here:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/754/370/original/print.jpg

Comment: Browsers differ in the format of date/time strings that they can parse. It would be best to avoid passing around human-readable strings, and instead return a numeric timestamp from the API.

Comment: Seems like this might be a closure issue, that updateClock isn't getting the value of startStamp.

Comment: @ViniciusDias r.start_time is the datetime I'm pulling from the database. It is formatted as 2016-10-24 13:57:30

Comment: @andi I've placed is inside the updateClock function and it still returns NaN. I'm starting to think that perhaps the issue is how the date and time is being passed from the database to the function variable. The datetime is placed in an array and then passed to the ajax callback. could this be an issue?

Comment: But you said `console.log(r.start_time)` shows you a date string?  where were you putting that console.log statement?

Comment: So What is the exact value of `r.start_time`? Is it an array?

Comment: @indi yes, it shows the date string correctly. I just pitched an idea thinking it might have something to do with the array being passed. I also noticed the following. if I manually do this var startDateTime = new Date(2016,10,24,13,57,30) it works but var startDateTime = new Date(2016-10-24 13:57:30) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
newStamp = newDate.getTime();
```

It should be:

```
newStamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Hope it's just this.

Comment: The previous line is `var newDate = new Date();`

Comment: Ops. My bad. I looked it in a hurry. Sorry.

Comment: newDate is a variable defined on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which was to change the date format in the mysql query before passing it to the ajax call. I formatted the datetime as DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s') and it worked.

It seems that the standard date format from the database YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is not interpreted by new Date(insert date here), thus resulting in NaN.